# How to send enum Type fields to GraphQL/AWS appsync from react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-appsync

This is code section.. companyStatus: userCtx.user.category  this section is generating error in the code. This field is actually enum type field in the schema.graphql
Can anyone please help me how to write that section? companyName is working fine, but getting error from company Status.

ERROR : companyType has an invalid value, this is the error

```
var input = {
        companyName: userCtx.user.company,
        companyStatus: userCtx.user.status 
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `userCtx.user.category` ? Is it a string or number ? Also, what are the possible values of this enum called `companyStatus` as per the graphql schema on the backend ?

Comment: Hey Thank you for getting back.
companyStatus is field type companyStatus.

Schema.graphql

enum companyStatus {
 active
 pending
 inactive
 delete
}

userCtx.user.category is pending

Comment: The thing is when I am adding the query from appsync, it's working as I am using pending without "" double quotes. But in react code, that double quotes is again coming in, I hope the error is for that reason.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The code was all ok.
My Schema was

```
companyStatus {
pending
active
inactive
}
```

In the code where I was receiving the `enum` value

```json
companyStatus: userCtx.user.status
```

`userCtx.user.status` value was previously `Pending`, P in caps, so that was the issue. When I changes `Pending` to `pending`, it got solved. Thanks.